# Why people use ProjectData

Tags: c#

Recently I looked at some coding at the web. I found some people use [`Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.ProjectData.ProjectData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.compilerservices.projectdata.aspx) class in `catch` block.

```
 catch (Exception exception1)
        {
            //ProjectData.SetProjectError(exception1);
            Console.WriteLine(exception1.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine(sSQL);
            //ProjectData.ClearProjectError();
        }
```

I searched it on msdn that mentioned that this API supports the .NET Framework infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code.

I am curious what reason  people use it. Would you explain it to me?

Comment: at the first glance, I believe the author is trying to set this exception as an internal VB error. the question should perhaps go to the author of the code you are referring to.

Comment: If you decompile an assembly built in VB using a reflector, you will find out that the VB compiler silently injects a lot of such calls

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My experience has been that this type of code use is found in c#/VB.NET projects that have been converted from VB6.  When developing new c#/VB.NET solutions/projects, this practice should not be used.

Note: This technique can safely be replaced with proper exception handling that you would be used to seeing in other .NET solutions/projects.

Answer (score 4):

This code is either emitted by a code conversion tool that converted VB code to C#, or resulted from decompiling an assembly that was originally created using VB.

I'm porting a VB project to Mono, and found out that the VB compiler injects these calls `ProjectData.SetProjectError(exception)` and `ProjectData.ClearProjectError()` in any catch block, and try to find a way to prevent the compiler from doing so because Mono doesn't implement the `ProjectData` module. And found your question while doing my research!

Answer (score 3):

so this is a result of old legacy vb6 for those interested. when vb6 started out there was an err object which is still around but has moved to the projectdata object in vb. if anybody like me remembers vb6 ( this is back when dinosaurs roamed the earth), there was a handy little call on error resume next. this is if you did not like those pesky little exceptions. most vb6 programs used it copiously and voila you had no exceptions because you ignored any. so here comes the explanation.

catch (Exception exception1) // catch any exceptions that just happened

```
    {

        ProjectData.SetProjectError(exception1); // set the information
```

//in the err object if anyone actually wants to check

```
        ProjectData.ClearProjectError(); //clear the err object
    }
```

as you can see this is completely ignoring any exceptions and in true vb6 fashion, your code just explodes without any explanation. needless to say if anyone writes code like this or uses vb in this way, I will find you and figure out a way to get you incarcerated.